# Linux Command line access to Citrix ICA desktop

Tags: linux, protocol, citrix

I have been asked to collect some data from a server on the "other side" of a Citrix ICA desktop.

I have access to TCP port 1494 on the Citrix server (ICA protocol) and what I am looking for is a Linux command line client that can connect to this port, authenticate to the Citrix server as needed, and then start an SSH process (or Putty) on the Citrix server to connect to the far server for data transfer.

I have played a bit with wfica on my Linux server but this appears to only open the $DISPLAY for GUI access. This collection needs to be automated via cron.

Any suggestions?